# Return from function in body and not only in last line in REST API Scala and play

Tags: scala, rest, playframework-2.1

I develop Rest API with scala and play framework.

In my product controller, I do validation of parameters received.
In case they fail from some reason, I would like to response with BadRequest in the middle of the function and not in the last line as scala works..
In the code below - Code continues running to the Ok line.. which is wrong, I want to **return** !

```
def getProduct(lang: String, t: String, ids: String) = Action {
 val productIdsList =  ids.split(",").toList 

 if (productIdsList.length.equals(1) && productIdsList(0).equals("")) //Validate input params are product Ids and not empty !
 {
    var errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, "No products IDs", 500)
    BadRequest(Json.toJson(errorResponse))//maybe return BadRequest(Json.toJson(errorResponse) ??
 }              

 val results = productService.getProducts(GetProductsRequest(lang,t,productIdsList));
 Ok(Json.toJson(results)) 
 // TODO: handle error
}
```

If implemented as:

```
return BadRequest(...)
```

It reply with error:

```
"method getProduct has return statement; needs result type"
```

I Understand this is bad practice, so what is the best practice for quitting the function without finishing it (and not throwing exceptions..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put an `else` branch, so there's nowhere to continue:

```
def getProduct(lang: String, t: String, ids: String) = Action {
 val productIdsList =  ids.split(",").toList 

 if (productIdsList.length.equals(1) && productIdsList(0).equals("")){ //Validate input params are product Ids and not empty !
    var errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, "No products IDs", 500)
    BadRequest(Json.toJson(errorResponse))//maybe return BadRequest(Json.toJson(errorResponse) ??
 }else{
    val results = productService.getProducts(GetProductsRequest(lang,t,productIdsList));
    Ok(Json.toJson(results)) 
    // TODO: handle error
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is good solution, but if i wish to return/break in the middle of the function, is there any option doing so ? or it considered bad practice in scala ??

Comment: I've never used `return` myself but I'm not an expert, so I don't know if this is a bad practice.

Comment: But validation can be done in many ways. For example have a look at this: https://coderwall.com/p/kokm7w. Or look at what `monads` are. `Try` or `Option` can help in some cases.